# Understanding <something>/.style={<bla bla>} syntax

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I'm having trouble finding good docs about this specific way of writing styles for latex documents.

The way I understand the grammar should be

```
<name of the command>/.style = {<options of the command you want to change> = new value}
```

What I tried is

```
\documentclass{report} 
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    draw/.style = {color=Blue}
    grid/.style = {color=Lavender}
}

\begin{document} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,cap=rect]
        \draw (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) grid (2,2);
        \draw (2,0) grid (4,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

and the previous code doesn't render anything visible at all, I also tried with just

```
\tikzset{
    draw/.style = {color=Blue}
}
```

but the result is the same.

What I'm getting wrong and what is the grammar of this ?

Comment: You are overriding the definition of `draw` etc in tikz. Try `mydraw/.style={draw, red, dashed}` and then for example `\node[my draw]{content}`

Comment: @Rmano can I get away without adding another element ? In this case `\node`

Comment: `\draw` means `\path[draw]`, and `[draw]` sets a flag so that the path will drawn.  Similarly, `\fill` means `\path[fill]` and `[fill]` sets a flag so that the path will be filled.  This is why `\drawfill`, `\draw[fill]`, `\fill[draw]`, `\path[draw, fill]` all mean the same thing.

Comment: The general convention in Ti*k*Z is that `every 〈blah〉/.style = {...}` sets the default behavior of 〈blah〉.  Examples are `every picture`, `every path`, and `every node`.  More can be found in the doc.  Go to the index and look for `every ...`.

Comment: "having trouble finding good docs" Have you *found* the TikZ manual (pgfmanual.pdf)?

Comment: @user202729 search for `.style` inside that manual results in a suggestion about how to customize snippets of your code, not a comprehensive description of the syntax and grammar of the command. It's more a collection of examples rather then a manual .

Comment: No, there are "formal documentation" in the manual (in my version I think it's in page 986, search for "`.style` handler" in the index) ; **however** that's probably not what most users want to read (e.g. what is `pgfkeys`!?), so just understand the syntax from the examples. Try the example out, see how it works, and infer the general syntax. (if necessary, tweak it step by step closer to what you want)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the basic idea. The syntax is

```
\tikzset{
    <firstname>/.style={<style elements>}, 
    <secondname>/.style={<style elements>}, 
    ...,
    <lastname>/.style={<style elements>}
}
```

You can create styles for nodes, lines and other objects (or for scopes or entire tikz pictures). In the example below, I define four styles, two I plan to use for nodes and two for lines. The syntax is the same. You can include any attribute that applies to that type of object. This setup is useful if you plan to use the same style of node (or line, or arrow, etc.) several times. There are more complicated things you can do with `tikzset` as well, but this should get you started.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    my big node/.style={violet, draw=blue, circle, minimum width=1.5cm},
    my little node/.style={draw=green,very thick,font=\tiny, rotate=90},
    my line/.style={<-,thick,orange},
    my other line/.style={line width=3pt,teal,dotted}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[draw] (A) at (0,0){default};
\node[my big node] (B) at (2,0){big};
\node[my little node] (C) at (4,0){small};
\node[fill=red] (D) at (6,0){};
\draw(A)--(B);
\draw[my line](B)--(C);
\draw[my other line](C)--(D);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: lastname needs a slash <lastname>/.style, not <lastname>.style

Comment: @BillNace, thanks. Fixed.

Comment: so the elements to draw is defined in the `.style` part and not in the invocation of the `\draw` command ?

Comment: also, I have to wrap anything in a node ? for example how to customize a cycled draw `\draw (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- cycle;` ( a triangle ) ?

Comment: @radm: For nodes, draw must be included if you want the node shape drawn. Try removing draw from the default node or from the defined node styles to see the effect. You can use the defined styles on your triangle also, for example, `\draw[my other line] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- cycle;`

Comment: ok, last question: can I combine 2 or more styles ?

Comment: @radm: Yes you can. If the styles both define the same property, the *second* one will take priority. For example, `\draw[my other line, my line](C)--(D);` will draw an orange, thick, left arrow, because of `my line` but it will be dotted because of `my other line`.